# What does preferring a player do?

Tags: overwatch

In OW, you can view current players on the server as well as recent players through the social tab.

If you right click on a name in the current game menu, there is an option to "Prefer Player".

Now I'm not sure what exactly this does, so I tried activating it.  I thought perhaps it would let me stay in the same team as him but for the next 4 matches, even though most of the server stuck around, including him, I was never matched with him once.

If anything, what does "preferring a player" do? If 6 players perfer one single player, and that player is the same, is it supposed to cluster them together? How does this work?

Comment: Your answer is probably platform dependent. On Xbox you can prefer players and it makes you more likely to be on their team, but that's a feature of Xbox Live.

Comment: But it's on PC as well, and Ps4, so much for platform independent

Comment: Yes, it's on PC and PS4, which don't have Xbox Live. That would make it platform dependent. Which platform are you on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you prefer a player, it will be more common that you will play with this player in the future without doing a party.

Comment: The "Prefer" system is still in the game (and "[working as intended](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20745404489)")

Comment: Does prefer attempt to put you on the same team or just in the same game?

Answer (score -1):

It will enable a feature that if that player you preferred is matchmaking at the same time as you, it will try to matchmake you with them.

Same thing with avoid a player, it will not let you play with that person in the future.